# In MS Word VBA, method to insert cross reference to the number of a numbered item using the number as it appears

Tags: vba, ms-word, cross-reference, numbered-list

I have the following code to insert an updating, hyperlinked cross-reference in place of a user-typed plain text number referring to a previous list item:

```
Selection.InsertCrossReference referencetype:="Numbered item", _
referencekind:=wdNumberNoContext, referenceitem:=<user-entered number>, 
InsertAsHyperlink:=True
```

I deal with documents with multiple numbered lists of different formatting, and the trouble is that if the user typed the number 5, the cross reference inserted will be to the 5th numbered item in the entire document, which may be a paragraph numbered "[0005]" instead of the user-intended list item numbered "5.", which appears much later in the document. I know it is possible to extract the list heading number as it appears for a given numbered item -- it is the ListString property of a ListFormat object; for example, `Selection.Range.ListFormat.ListString` will return the number as it appears for the selected paragraph.

But does this method have an inverse that will return a numbered item given its heading number as it appears, without having to explicitly iterate through paragraphs and extract the ListString property of each paragraph that is a ListFormat object until a match is found?

Comment: No, there's nothing like that. But you could cut down the overhead by iterating throught Document.ListParagraphs, which would leave out unnumbered paragraphs. Or convert all numbering to text so that you can use Find, set a bookmark, then Undo the conversion.

Comment: I think this might be an XY problem.  Why do you want to do this?  From your question, I think you are trying to autonumber references in dependent claims to parent claims.  Right?  Or are you working on FIG. numbers, part numbers, or table numbers?  (Or several of those?)  In general, I have had more success bookmarking things I want to refer to, and using cross references to the bookmarks, than I have had referring to autonumbers.  (And a hyperlinked reference to a paragraph is just a reference to a hidden bookmark anyway.)

Comment: @CindyMeister most of the paragraphs in the document are numbered. The numbering format is different for the two different styles, but the referenceitem property ignores the difference and simply numbers all list formatted paragraphs sequentially. Converting to text, using find, setting a bookmark, and then undoing the conversion could work in theory, though it seems like it might be "heavy" to run.

Comment: @cxw You are correct; I want auto-updating cross references to parent claims. But I don't want to have to manually add bookmarks to all of the claims, as that would be almost as cumbersome as manually adding a cross reference to the numbered item. I want to type "the apparatus of claim 10", backselect "claim 10", hit my macro keystroke, and make the "10" an auto-updating field, so that if I insert claims before claim 10 I don't have to manually renumber. I just ctrl+A and f9 to update all fields. I don't care so much about the hyperlinking as the auto-updating, but they go hand-in-hand.

Comment: PatentWookiee, we should talk shop about our common interests sometime :) .  I think I left you some obfuscated contact information in a comment on a different question (you know how to de-obfuscate it).  If not, do you have a public key that I can use to send you the info?

Comment: @CindyMeister I will accept as your answer, if you want to post it, that there is no inverse method to return a Paragraph from its .Range.ListFormat.ListString property, but that a solution for my specific situation is to count the number n of Paragraphs listPara in Document.ListParagraphs with the numbering style [0001] etc. (I tested each listPara.ListFormat.ListString against a regular expression), and to substitute n+<user-entered number> for <user-entered number> in my posted code to insert the desired cross-reference. It works as I intended now.

Comment: @cxw I cannot believe a world of highly paid lawyers has not already commissioned a solution for automatic insertion of paragraph references. As a programmer having to write a single affidavit I'm already out of my mind. I **will** have a markdown style `see ![para51(a)-(c)] for details` even if it has to be written as an external utility.  I think the key maybe somewhere between `Document.ListParagraphs`, `.Style`, `Document.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeNumberedItem)` and `Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber`, depending on your document style.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I have created a full solution for doing this, though the output is only in alpha stage.

https://gist.github.com/sfinktah/789cfb36b3b15025d5796433da68ffb4

Assign the last sub on the page to Shift-Alt-F9 or somesuch,type 31(a),45 or somesuch, then press Shift-Alt-F9 twice (once to select the previous text, and once to convert it into references).  I may develop it properly one day as a legal helper-app.

I believe all the concepts you need are contained in this demonstration.

It both iterates all numbered paragraphs, inserting a reference to each paragraph as it goes. It will probably break if there is a paragraph with less than 2 words, or insert multiple references -- this is just a starting point.

To generate a reference to specific and [complex] numbered paragraph such as 1(a)(i), you would iterate all numbered paragraphs until you found your matching paragraph. There is a ListLevel value you can use to build a complete "1(a)(i)" string as you iterate.

Once matched, it calls the second function which creates a reference based on the ListLevelNumber and joined words that comprise the paragraph -- that required some special trial and error work, and probably isn't perfect.

```vb
Public Sub InsertParagraphReference(ByRef doc As word.Document, _
                                    ByRef sel As word.Selection, _
                                    match As String)
    myHeadings = _
        doc.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeNumberedItem)
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(myHeadings)
        If InStr(LTrim(myHeadings(i)), match) = 1 Then
            count = count + 1
            With sel
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
                .InsertBefore "paragraph "
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                .InsertCrossReference _
                    ReferenceType:=wdRefTypeNumberedItem, _
                    ReferenceKind:=wdNumberFullContext, ReferenceItem:=i, _
                    InsertAsHyperlink:=True, IncludePosition:=True
                .InsertAfter ", "
                ' Be careful of inserting newlines, as endless loops can occur
                ' if you are making a new list-item each time.
                ' vbCr
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            End With
        End If
    Next i
    If count = 0 Then
        With sel
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
            .InsertBefore "failed_match: '" & match & "'"
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            .InsertParagraphAfter
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Public Function JoinWords(ByRef words As Variant) As String
    Dim joined As String
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0
    For Each aWord In words
        aWord = FilterWord(aWord)
        If Len(aWord) > 0 Then
            If aWord.Characters(1) > Chr(31) Then
                joined = joined + aWord
                count = count + 1
            End If
        End If
        If count > 10 Then Exit For
    Next aWord
    JoinWords = joined
End Function

Public Function FilterWord(ByRef word As Variant) As String
    Dim filtered As String
    Dim ord As Integer
    filtered = ""
    Dim length As Integer
    length = Len(word)
    For i = 1 To length
        ord = Asc(word.Characters(i))
        If ord > 31 Then filtered = filtered + Char
        If ord = 11 Then filtered = filtered + " "
    Next i
    FilterWord = filtered
End Function
    
Sub IterateNumberedParagraphsAndReference()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim joined As String
    ' .ListParagraphs iterates in reverse order, so use .Paragraph and filter
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        With para.Range
            If .ListParagraphs.count > 0 Then
                joined = JoinWords(.words)
                If 0 Then
                    MsgBox "Style: " & para.Style _
                        & " OutlineLevel: " & para.OutlineLevel _
                        & " ListLevel: " & .ListFormat.ListLevelNumber _
                        & " Text: " & .ListFormat.ListString & " " _
                            & "'" & RTrim(joined) & "'"
                End If
                InsertParagraphReference ActiveDocument, Selection, _
                .ListFormat.ListString & " " & RTrim(joined)
                
             End If
        End With
    Next para
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses a dictionaries to store the numbered items and reference numbers.

```
Function ReadNbrs() As Variant
    Dim vList, vItem, vSplit, vReturn
    Dim dRefText As Object
    Dim dRefNbr As Object
    Dim dRef as Object

    'return text given nbr
    Set dRefText = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'return nbr given text
    Set dRefNbr = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'return reference item number
    Set dRef = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    vList = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeNumberedItem)

    For Each vItem in vList
        'delimiter depends on your lists ... space, tab, other?
        vSplit = Split(vItem, vbTab)
        dRefNbr(vSplit(1)) = vSplit(0)
        dRefText(vSplit(0)) = vSplit(1)
        dRef(vSplit(0)) = dRef.Count + 1
    Next vItem

    vReturn = Array(dRef, dRefNbr, dRefText)
    ReadNbrs = vReturn

Exit Function
```

Not really clear on the original intent; however, I was automating inserting the cross references, and used dRef to get the reference item number for the `Range.InsertCrossReference` method:

`Range.InsertCrossReference wdRefTypeNumberedItem, wdNumberFullContext, dRef(sKey), True, True, False, " "`, where sKey was the text in the document that is replaced by the hyperlinked cross reference.